# Back end users settings is reset when editing a text element

Tags: php, javascript, html, typo3

The user settings are saved in be_users.uc
But when the user edits a text element the settings are removed and the field is almost empty.
This only occurs on one page and for all users.
The users are admins.

It seems like it's the HTML that generate the bug. Can a lot of HTML do this?!
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kSxWt/) is the HTML that the user has inserted

Comment: I think you would be better off asking at Typo3

Comment: Looks like a paste from MS Word, you'll probably want to do some cleansing on the data before processing it. Have you tried it by sending regular text to the page?

Comment: @PadraigD Yes and the error seems to disappear. But I think it's weird that html can do that.

Comment: The thing is, it's not HTML that is being posted back. It is a load of MS Word meta-data that is being posted about formatting, etc. You'll need to look into a function for cleansing MS Word pastes. I'm sure a Google search will sort you out.

Comment: Better use the RTE and the paste box for MS Word (crap) content.

Comment: Looks like this is worth being filed as a bug on forge.typo3.org

Answer (score 0):

I guess, TYPO3 tries to write more data into uc than it is allowed. The data is serialized, so you can see which entry is too big.

For debugging purpose you can increase the field size of be_users.uc or you can just save the record and have a look into be_users.uc after that. Perhaps you can paste that? I guess you will see some really large entries there. May be it helps to solve the issue.